# Table design to support pending changes

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a `users` table. Users can belong to a group. For them I have a `group` table, with id, title and description.

Now, any changes in the group table must be approved by an admin. So, I need a (preferably fast & easy) way to handle both live and pending group data.

I thought about having a `status` field in the group table and adding a new record whenever a group is edited. But what do I do when the edit is approved? Copy the title and description back to the live record and delete the pending one? If I delete the old record and mark the new one as live, then I need to update all users records that use the old group_id to the new one. Also, all pending records would need to reference the live records...

Is there a better solution? Part of me just want to say 'forget it' and simply duplicate the fields - have a `live_title` and a `pending_title`.

I'm using MySQL. I prefer a solution that is fast and easy to implement (I need to build an API for it).

Comment: Pending records and approved records are 2 different entity types. Pending is template, approved is instance. Yes, they are similar visually... but their actions are absolutely different. 2 entities - 2 tables. One can be converted to another - move from table to table.

Comment: Using two tables was my initial gut feeling as well. But then the more I read on the issue, the more doubts I had.

Comment: If only title changes, why do you need to update all users records? Isn't there a `group_id` or similar?

Comment: I simplified a bit. The group table holds more stuff. My dilemma was about handling the approval. Do I copy the pending record over the live record? Or delete the live record and the pending becomes live? Second method seemed messier. Using a separate table altogether seems better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pending table is a better concept. It only gets used to create and approve pending elements.

Approval is a transaction:

```
  BEGIN;

  INSERT INTO title
  SELECT * 
  FROM pending_title
  WHERE id = {x};

  DELETE FROM pending_title
  WHERE id = {x};

  COMMIT
```

This will simplify the lookup logic so you don't need `status=approved` in every other SQL query.